# How to find states given TCP flags as observable states in HMM

Tags: tcp, machine-learning, probability, hidden-markov-models

I am implementing HMM(Hidden markov model).I have obtained a dataset of TCP flags such as Synchronized, Reset, Acknowledgement, FIN/ACK, PUSH/ACK. 
The problem is I have to find the number of states so that I can calculate the conditional probabilities, transition probabilities, emission probabilities.

I have assumed random number of states considering the TCP flags as observables. Using [Baum-Welch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm) algorithm calculated the transition as well as emission probabilities. But taking random number of states we do not know whether the output is accurate.

So we are trying to find a better way to find out number of states and specifically which are the states to be used.
We are trying to implement the following paper [Adaptive IDS using hybrid approach](http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~ravi/papers/Ranga_COMSNETS_12.pdf).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thinks are easier or I do not understand the question.

SYN, SYN/ACK, ... are TCP flags. Interpret them as a first classification of TCP messages, so, as TCP message types. These are the events in the TCP finite-state machine.

The states of TCP finite state machine are CLOSE_WAIT, FIN_WAIT_1, ... . In total, 12 states.

If you look for "tcp state machine" in google images, you will easily find a draw of the state machine. By example: http://www.ssfnet.org/Exchange/tcp/Graphics/tcpStateDiagram1.gif

Synchronized is not a TCP flag nor state.